# How to combine and append two json files by using common key without losing other data

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have two json files which have several json objects.
I want to merge two json files on linux by using jq with group_by(.id)
Actually I don't need to use jq but I need to make linux shell script files.

Of course I tried to many solutions but they didn't work exactly like what I want.

Input 1: file1.json

```
{"id":"1234", "branch": "master", "arr":["say", "one", "more"]}
{"id":"102", "branch": "master", "arr":["yes"]}
{"id":"1228", "branch": "master"}
```

Input 2: file2.json

```
{"id":"1234", "branch": "dev", "other": "value", "arr":["what"]}
{"id":"102", "branch": "dev"}
{"id":"0806", "branch": "master"}
```

What I expect is

```
{"id":"1234", "branch": ["master", "dev"], "other": "value", "arr":["say", "one", "more", "what"]}
{"id":"102", "branch": ["master", "dev"], "arr":["yes"]}
{"id":"1228", "branch": "master"}
{"id":"0806", "branch": "master"}
```

but the actual output is like

```
{"id":"1234", "branch": "dev", "other": "value", "arr":["what"]}
{"id":"102", "branch": "dev"}
{"id":"0806", "branch": "master"}
```

Comment: Can your shell script depend on external interpreters like Node, Python, PHP, Perl, etc.?

Comment: @fardjad Not actually. Jq is familiar. That's why I want to use jq. So honestly, it doesn't matter using other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, we use the generic function `combine` for combining two objects, as defined below.

With this function, and using an invocation such as:

```
jq -n -f combine.jq --slurpfile f1 file1.json --slurpfile f2 file2.json
```

and assuming your jq has `INDEX/2`, then a solution can be obtained by simply writing:

```
INDEX( $f1[]; .id) as $d1
| INDEX( $f2[]; .id) as $d2
| reduce (($d1+$d2)|keys_unsorted)[] as $id
    ({}; .[$id] = ($d1[$id] | combine($d2[$id])) )
| .[]
```

That is, we construct a dictionary for each of the two files, and then combine the objects at the corresponding keys, and then produce the desired stream.

If your installation of jq does not have `INDEX/2`, then now would be a good time to upgrade, but an alternative would be to copy its def from builtin.jq (see the "comment" below).

### combine/1

In the following, which is intended for jq 1.5 or later, the details of combining values are left to the inner function, `aggregate`.

```
# Combine . with obj using aggregate/2 for shared keys whose values differ
def combine($obj):

  # Combine two entities in an array-oriented fashion:
  # if both are arrays:  a + b 
  # else if a is an array: a + [b]
  # else if b is an array: [a] + b
  # else [a, b]
  def aggregate(a; b):
    if (a|type) == "array" then
      if (b|type) == "array" then a + b
      else a + [b]
      end
    else
      if (b|type) == "array" then [a] + b
      else [a, b]
      end
    end;

  if . == null then $obj
  elif $obj == null then .
  else reduce ($obj|keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.;
         if .[$key] == $obj[$key] then . 
         else .[$key] = if has($key) and ($obj|has($key))
                        then aggregate( .[$key]; $obj[$key] )
                        else .[$key] + $obj[$key]
                end
         end )
   end ;
```

Comment: I made **combine.jq** and invoked `jq -n -f combine.jq --slurpfile f1 file1.json --slurpfile f2 file2.json` but the **result is null**.

Comment: combine.jq assumes you are running jq version 1.6; if your jq does not have INDEX/2, then simply copy its def e.g. from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: I upgrade jq to 1.6 and I also tried copying def `def index($i):   indices($i) | .[0];` from the link. But the result is still null.

Comment: Do not copy `def index`!!!  First, jq 1.6 already has `def INDEX`; second, `def INDEX` has nothing to do with `def index`.

Comment: Great. Maybe you could explain so others can benefit.